# Make registry entries or call custom code from a VSIX package

Tags: visual-studio-2015, registry, vsix, visual-studio-templates

Is there any way to make registry entries in a VSIX package to execute custom routines in C#.

I could also make the registry entries programmatically if any C# routine can be called.

Comment: Just use the registry API from within your package !?

Comment: Yes, but don't know how to use it in vstemplate. Do you have an example ?

Comment: Is it a vsix with code or just some templates?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. A VSIX file is nothing more than a .ZIP file used to deploy various extensions for VS. Meaning a VSIX could contain a VSPackage, an editor extension, a project or item template, etc.

When you say "execute custom routines in C#" you need to elaborate as to whey you want these routings invoked. Do you want to invoke them via a menu item, or some event that occurs in the IDE. And when you mention the registry, what sort of changes do you need to make and for what purpose. Thanks.